# Jquery show when hidden

Tags: jquery

I have this problem which is killing me ;(

I have the following HTML, all texto are hidden by css

```
<p><b><a class="titulo" href="#">Title</a></b></p>
<div class='texto'><p>Some text</p></div>

<p><b><a class="titulo" href="#">Title</a></b></p>
<div class='texto'><p>Some text</p></div>

<p><b><a class="titulo" href="#">Title</a></b></p>
<div class='texto'><p>Some text</p></div>

<div class='callToAtion bottomline'>
<a class="btnMeInteresa" href="#">Me interesa</a>
<a href="#">No, gracias</a> 
</div>
```

I want the bottomline class to be shown ONLY when all texto are hidden. I have the following jquery, but doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.titulo').click(function(){
        $($(this).closest('p').next()).slideToggle();

        if ($('.texto:visible').length === 0){
            $('.bottomline').show();
        }
        else {
            $('.bottomline').hide();
        }
        return false;
    })
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI: You can replace that whole if block with a much more succinct:    $('.bottomline').toggle($('.texto').is(':visible'));

Comment: @JohnFx: VERY good point, I folded that into my answer. Classic case of not stepping back.

Answer (score 3):

`slideToggle` is an animation, so you have to wait for it to end before you can determine whether any are visible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.titulo').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('p').next().slideToggle(function() {
      if ( $('.texto:visible').length === 0)
      {
          $('.bottomline').show();
      }
      else
      {
          $('.bottomline').hide();
      }
    });     
    return false;
  });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/icezif/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/icezif/1/edit)

Alternately, check ahead of time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.titulo').click(function(){
    var texto = $(this).closest('p').next();
    var targetCount = texto.is(":visible") ? 1 : 0;
    var last = $('.texto:visible').length === targetCount;
    texto.slideToggle();
    if (last)
    {
        $('.bottomline').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.bottomline').hide();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/icezif/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/icezif/2/edit)

Taking inspiration from [JohnFx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30018/johnfx)'s comment on the question:

Example 1 updated:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.titulo').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('p').next().slideToggle(function() {
      $('.bottomline').toggle(!$('.texto').is(':visible'));
    });     
    return false;
  });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/icezif/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/icezif/3/edit)

Example 2 updated:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.titulo').click(function(){
    var texto = $(this).closest('p').next();
    var targetCount = texto.is(":visible") ? 1 : 0;
    var last = $('.texto:visible').length === targetCount;
    texto.slideToggle();
    $('.bottomline').toggle(last);
    return false;
  });
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/icezif/4) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/icezif/4/edit)

Comment: Right idea.  Wrong execution.  You have to pass a function to `slideToggle()` not just a block of code.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yeah, bit of a typo there. Fixed.

Comment: hah... cmon you and i both know that's just a typo. you have edit rights don't you?